# VB.Net - How to replace an array with another array in a text

Tags: vb.net

I've been searching, and I found some similar questions, but none of them are solution for me, so what I need is this in Visual Basic:

I have a text *(string)* and I have two Arrays like this:

```
Dim data_array_one As String() = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"}
Dim data_array_two As String() = {"Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"}
```

What I need is replace every “*One*” in a text for “*Five*”, every “*Two*” for “*Six*”, and so...
I've been using a simple replace function:

```
text1 = text1.Replace("One", "Five")
text1 = text1.Replace("Two", "Six")
...
```

But now array contains 24 elements, and every day it increments automatically, so I need something to do it automatically from arrays instead the actual way...
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Is it a 1:1 mapping between arrays one and two ?

Comment: Yes, I need to replace it, first with first, second with second, third with third, and so...

Comment: This is not very optimal but you could try something like `for (i=0; i< arrayLength;i++) {text1 = text1.Replace(array1[i], array2[i]);}`.

Comment: Do you need to handle issues like partial matches?  Using `String.Replace` to replace "Four" with "Eight" will also cause "Fourteen" to become a misspelled "Eightteen".  Probably not what you want.

Comment: @ryadavilli It's a VB.NET question so and answer in C# isn't useful.

Comment: @ClaraOnager and hence I did not post it as answer. I just gave an idea of how the loop would look in C#. The OP can covert this for loop to VB was my assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this as a simplistic fix.

```
dim i as single

For i = 0 to data_array_one.getlength(0)
text1 = text1.Replace(data_array_one(i), data_array_two(i))
next
```

However it isn't very efficient and as tcarvin said in a comment to your question, this could lead to problems with "Four" being replaced in "Fourteen".